# Why is "vkCreateInstance" causing vulkan demos and example code to crash?

Tags: dll, vulkan, amd-processor

Vulkan failing to launch. Exception when `vkCreateInstance` is called.

I've looked all over the place and no solutions regarding this function are solving my problem unfortunately.

I suspect there are some bad AMD files in the `System32` folder (gotta love how they place x64 files in here and x86/32 in `SysWOW64`) causing Vulkan to crash.

When "Vulkan Info" is typed into the windows search bar, a cmd momentarily pops up and then decides to close (really?). I managed to get a screen capture right before it does and it states that

> amd-vulkan32.json does not have an 'api_version' field.

This file has a misspelling in it: `abi_versions` when I assume it should be `api_versions`.

Deleting the file allows the cube example and base code with an instance to run, but does not work for more advanced programs.  Updating my drivers does not change this file or the others.

I'm having a hard time understanding why these AMD files are here. Are they aimed towards a CPU, GPU, or are they generalized? I have a Nvidia graphics card so GPU dlls don't really make sense (integrated CPU graphics? I do have a Ryzen), unless maybe there once was a Radeon card in this PC and these are leftover drivers.
Am I correct in assuming these files are entirely to blame or is there something else I'm missing that's causing Vulkan to crash?

```
vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance);
```

Comment: You don't need screencap. Just open `cmd` then run `vulkaninfo`. Yes, it is likely integrated GPU; check Device Manager if you have AMD gpu. Then install drivers from AMD website; Windows Update might have installed some old garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KrOoze, you were right in that the drivers were bad. Nvidia is the only display adapter listed though. Removed all AMD drivers using "Display Driver Uninstaller" this time and reinstalled the Vulkan SDK to fix another error that popped up afterwards.

The cube example works again, and I suppose that's all I really need for what I'm trying to do.

I think I'll move back to Modern OpenGL for now though, the Vulkan code is just too verbose and hardware specific, at least from what I've experienced.